# Slow iteration through elements in WatiN

Tags: c#, performance, watin

I'm writing an application with Watin. Its great, but running a performance analysis on my program, over 50% of execution time is spent looping through lists of elements.

For example:
    foreach (TextField bT in browser.TextFields)
    {

Is very slow.

I seem to remember seeing somewhere there is a faster way of doing this in WatiN, but unfortunately I can't find the page again.

Accessing the number of elements also seems to be slow, eg;
    browser.CheckBoxes.Count

Thanks for any tips,
Chris

Comment: It uses `IE` as the internal engine...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I could answer you better if I had a better idea of what you were trying to do, but I can share some observations on what I've learned with WatiN so far.

The more specific your selectors are, the faster things will go. Avoid using "browser.Elements" as that is really generic. I'm not sure that it saves much, but doing something like browser.Body.Elements throws the header elements out of the scope of things to check and may save a few calculations.

When I say "scope", consider that WatiN always starts with the entire DOM. Can you think of ways to limit the scope of elements perhaps to the text fields within the main div on your page? WatiN returns Elements and ElementCollections, each of which may have its own ElementCollection. That div probably has a specific ID, so you can do something like

```
var textFields = ie.Div("divId").TextFields;
```

Look for opportunities to be more specific, and you can use LINQ to describe what you want more clearly. For example, can you write something like:

```
ie.Body.TextFields.
  Where(tf => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tf.ClassName) && tf.ClassName.Contains("classname")).ToList().
  Foreach(tf => tf.Value = "Your Text");
```

I would refine that further by reducing the number of times I scan the collection by doing something like:

```
ie.Body.TextFields.ToList().
  Foreach(tf => {
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tf.ClassName) && tf.ClassName.Contains("classname")) { 
      tf => tf.Value = "Your Text"
    }
  });
```

The "Find.By*" specifiers also help WatiN operate on the collections you want faster and are a more elegant short-hand for what I wrote above:

```
ie.Body.TextFields.Filter(Find.ByClass("class")).ToList().ForEach(tf => tf.Value = "Your Text");
```

And as a last piece of advice, [this project](http://davidkirk.wordpress.com/2009/12/15/jquery-style-css-selectors-for-watin/) lets you find elements using jQuery/CSS style selectors.

So, **tl;dr:** Narrow down the scope of what you're looking for, and be specific.

Hope that helps. I'm looking for ways to speed up my own tests.

Comment: Thanks Dahv for a really detailed answer. In my case I've sped up my tests by about 10x using a number of tricks, some similar to yours:

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to iterate through all text fields, there is no other way. As @Xaqron pointed out, it depends on IE. But maybe you just need to iterate through text fields of eg. specified `<div/>`? Finding it first, and then iterating through it's text fields would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dahv for a really detailed answer. In my case I've sped up my tests by about 10x using a number of tricks, some similar to yours:

- Refining scope as you and prostynick (in my case using Form1.TextField  etc.)
- First checking if browser.html matches my regex before seeing if
  fields do
- Using the GehSoft.PRCE RegEx wrapper - its native code regex
  matching is far faster than .NET's for small haystacks. So to find a TextField I'd do:

  ```
      Gehtsoft.PCRE.Regex regexString = new Gehtsoft.PCRE.Regex("[Nn]ame");
        foreach (TextField bT in browser.TextFields)
                      {
                          //Skip if no match
                          if (!regexString.Execute(bT.Name).Success) continue;
  ```
- Before I was looping on a list of regexes, then inside that i was looping on TextFields. Making the TextFields loop the top loop improved speed about 3x.